# How to prevent data changes in excel

Tags: excel, vba

Good morning,
I have tables with data. Most of them are numbers but some of them contains letters. I need to use "pastespecial" property from range. 
The problem is that sometimes I have number like :
5924017E7 and excel convert it to 59240170000000.

```
Range("A5").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlMultiply, _
SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
```

I was trying to define column as "General", "Number", "Text" and define Selection.NumberFormat to proper value but for this number "5924017E7" it doesn't work. Is is changing it no matter what.
How to prevent this change?

Answer (score 0):

If you change this:

`Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlMultiply, _
SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False`

With this:

`Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False`

It should do it